# Customer Store / Website Not Matching

Tags: customer, multistore, customer-account, websites

We have a Magento installation that has 2 websites (IDs 1 & 2 in `core_website`), each has 1 store (IDs 1 & 2 in `core_store`), with the ID's of the stores matching the ID of the website it's associated with. I recently noticed that we have occurrences of customers who's `website_id` doesn't match their `store_id` in the `customer_entity` table. It's only ~0.05% of customers, but I can't work out how this could be possible. If somebody is registering from `Store 2` this should surely necessitate that they are registering from `Website 2`.

Can anybody shed some light on how this might occur and perhaps more importantly whether it can lead to any problems?

Comment: Are there any users that are assigned to the store_id = 0?

Comment: A handful, but the majority are 2 & 1. We actually checked a different client and can see they have the same 'issue'.

Comment: It won't cause any problems if Share Customer Accounts is set to Global (Configuration > Customer Configuration).

Comment: Which it is. Do you have any idea what causes it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into something completely unrelated, I have come across the reason behind this. `Mage_Newsletter_ManageController::saveAction`, which is triggered by saving the Newsletter subscription tab in the customer account changes the store_id of the customer to match the current store.